# How to take screenshot and share it from program to social media(Facebook,Telegram and other)?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, share

I make a screenshot on page and I want to share it to social media. I do not know how to share image to the social media. I know only how to share text, but I need to share image.Please help me to share screenshot from program

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30">

            <StackLayout x:Name="header">
                <Frame
                    Padding="3"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    BorderColor="#DBDBDB"
                    CornerRadius="15"
                    HasShadow="False">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackLayout
                            Margin="5,0,0,0"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            Orientation="Horizontal">

                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                    Text="USD"
                                    TextColor="Black" />
                                <Label
                                    FontSize="10"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                    Text="US Dollar"
                                    TextColor="Black" />
                            </StackLayout>


                        </StackLayout>

                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>

            <Button x:Name="ShareButton" Text="Share" />
            <Image x:Name="result" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>



 public async void Button_Clicked(Object o,EventArgs e)
        {
            var image =await header.CaptureImageAsync();
            result.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => image);

        }
```

It is code how I make screenshot.Please help me to share image from program to social media

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=android

Comment: Can you help me to save my image to File?

Comment: there are numerous existing posts about saving streams to file in C#

Comment: If you want to ask how to take a screenshot and then share it you should update your question title and description, so that others with the same problem may find it and get help from it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/?context=xamarin/android) for all that.

For example, if you want to share a screenshot you can [save the screenshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/screenshot#using-screenshot) to a file (demo code):

```
async Task<string> CaptureScreenshotAsync()
{
    var screenshot = await Xamarin.Essentials.Screenshot.CaptureAsync();
    var stream = await screenshot.OpenReadAsync();
    var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "screenshot.png");
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
        await fs.FlushAsync();
    }
    return file;
}
```

and then [share this file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=android#file) (demo code):

```
async Task ShareFile(string filename, string filepath) 
{
    await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest()
            {
                Title = filename,
                File = new ShareFile(filepath)
            });
}
```

**Note:** You should make sure the file extension is correct. I experienced some problems sharing or opening files with no or wrong file extensions.

Comment: Please help me to save my image to File